# Java Package Program compilation in Linux

Tags: java

I had created two packages in linux. one package inherits other. I am getting error while compiling the inherited package. Please tell me what are the commands to compile and execute Package programs.

Comment: Packages can not inherit anything. Do you mean a Class?

Comment: There is no "Package Program".

Comment: Maybe that's what you need > http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/linux-cmd.html

Comment: Yes second Package class inherits first package class.

Answer (score 0):

From what ever that was understood from the question:

Well compile the parent project first, build a jar out of it, and then compile the second project, with the first jar in `CLASSPATH`.  Thats how its achieved.

Comment: In linux jar cannot be there. For package file i created a directory. Since we use in college server we cannot set classpath.